# Popular uma List com dados do banco acessados pelo EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Como popular minha *List*, em C#, com os dados armazenados no banco de dados acessados através do EntityFramework?

Código atual:

```
 public static IEnumerable<Contato> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<Contato> { //DAqui pa frente nao sei para onde ir . . .//
```

Comment: Qual tecnologia de acesso ao banco esta utilizando?

Comment: entity-framework

Comment: A edição não ajuda muito, mas pelo menos se tem um pouco mais de contexto.

Comment: A questão está resolvida? Considere marcar uma resposta como aceita.
*[Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079)*

Answer (score 3):

Considerenado que você já possui sua classe que herda de DbContext configurada para trabalhar com o Entity Framework... exemplo:

```
public partial class SeuDBContext : DbContext
{
    ...     
    public DbSet<Contato> Contatos { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Além de sua entidade mapeada, acredito que no método em si você poderia fazer apenas isso:

```
public IEnumerable<Contato> GetAll()
{
    using(var context = new SeuDBContext())
    { 
        return context.Contatos;
    }
}
```